# Use Service Bus as a push notification workaround (excluding Notification Hub)

Tags: push-notification, servicebus

I'm developing an on-site WinRT application and would like to send push notifications when a new update is available (since it's an on-site app, the installation process requires a custom loader rather than the Windows Store app).

However, I'm trying to wrap my head around how such a system should ideally function.

I could obviously create a service which returns the latest version number and the app would periodically poll the service for that info. It would be easy to implement, but it seems like a very ugly approach (the need to send constant requests for the latest version doesn't seem like an elegant one).

I have the power of Azure at my disposal. Obviously a Notification Hub would be the preferred way. HOWEVER, I have no intention of getting a Windows Store account purely to develop a "private" on-site application. So using the Notification Hub is a no-go.

I've thought about using topics. This WOULD work, but every client would probably need to be added as a subscriber. While technically possible, the administrative overhead could be a major issue. I also thought about creating the subscribers dynamically by the WinRT application itself. However the SDK ([Azure Messaging Managed](https://www.nuget.org/packages/WindowsAzure.Messaging.Managed/)) for handling this is too old and always throws an error (invalid date format, which apparently was changed at some point) when creating subscribers. The only "current" package from MS seems to be for the full .NET framework, not the limited WinRT counterpart.

I'm looking for ways around this problem. Either a newer, proper SDK (which can handle listing and creating subscriptions as well as receiving topic), or perhaps a completely different approach to the problem.

Note - I don't need any code just yet. Pseudocode or simply a description on how the communication would work should suffice.

Answer (score 0):

For a limited scale deployment, Service Bus Topics may quite well be a feasible choice. Or you may want to take a look at IoT Hub as an alternative push notification channel.

The new Service Bus client SDK for .NET Standard lives this repo, but we do not build binaries as of yet: https://github.com/Azure/azure-service-bus-dotnet